# How to upload image and save it to my current workspace?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, hibernate, maven

I try to create my own eshop and I would like when I am admin to imaga photo for the items and this image would be saved on my current workspace. So when the users search for an item they can see images.

The real problem is how to find the working space and save the images to the folder named: "**images**" at the path: **WEB-INF/resources/images**.

I have tried:

```
Path currentRelativePath = Paths.get("");
String s = currentRelativePath.toAbsolutePath().toString();
System.out.println("Current relative path is:" + s);
```

The output is:

```
Current relative path is:C:\Users\mike\Desktop
```

And this one:

```
System.out.println("Working directory = " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

The output is:
    Working directory = C:\Users\mike\Desktop
And finally:

```
    System.out.println("Working directory = " + Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toString());
```

The output is:

```
Working directory = C:\Users\peace\Desktop
```

The real working path where I want to save my images is:

```
D:\Michalis_study\Spring\eMusicStore24\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\resources\images
```

So what can I do ? I am working on Eclipse.

**EDIT**
I also tried:
    String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
    path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "//WEB-INF//resources//images//" + product.getProductId() + ".png");

But the image is saved at the following path:

```
D:\Michalis_study\Spring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\eMusicStore24\WEB-INF\resources\images\8.png
```

**EDIT 2**

**Path that the image is saved:**

```
D:\Michalis_study\Spring\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\eMusicStore24\WEB-INF\resources\images\9.png
```

**Path that I would like to save the image**

```
D:\Michalis_study\Spring\eMusicStore24\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\resources\images
```

As you can see the 2 paths does not differ a lot.

Except this part of path

```
\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp3\wtpwebapps\
```

The 2nd path is closed to the path that I want to save the images but this cannot help me to save the images to right place to load for the users who want to see info for an item.

I try to take the path with the following code:

```
String rootDirectory =   request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
System.out.println("rootDirectory " + rootDirectory);
path = Paths.get(rootDirectory + "WEB-INF//resources//images//" + product.getProductId() + ".png");
System.out.println("path = " + path);
```

So, what can I do with this code? Probably I am trying to take the path with wrong way. 
Finally, there is no differnce if I write:

```
rootDirectory + "//WEB-INF....
```

or

```
rootDirectory + "/WEB-INF....
```

The final path is the same...

Comment: Why do you wnat to save your images under "/WEB-INF/" ? Static files like css, images and js are saved out of "WEB-INF" directory, so you "ressources" folder should be out.

Comment: @akuma8 hi once again. I would like to save images at the "/WEB-INF/" folder when I am logged in as admin so the users can see these images for each item. So what can I do? I have to save in other path (or folder) the images?

Comment: To be more specific I would like, if someone logged in as admin and want to add an item (with an image) the image can be saved somewhere in order for users to be able to see this image..

Comment: You have a "ressources" folder witch has the same level as "WEB-INF/" in your project directory, so you can use it. Or put your images in the file system and then load them with "File()"

Comment: Have a nice week @akumae8. I edited my first post..
Can you explain how to use the File()? Because as I mention in the post tha path that image is saved is false when I try to "save" to into my project folder...

Comment: Hi, sorry for this long absence. Did you solve your problem?

Comment: Hi. Finally, I uploaded my project to cloud and the photos are uploaded fine.